# Update MultiSelect picklist from Journey Builder Object Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is it possible to update MultiSelect picklist field with multiple values from Marketing cloud Journey using Sales cloud activity for e.g. Object Activity?
Trying to update Multiselect picklist with DE Attribute value as A;B;C or A; B; C.
In Object Activity Mutiselect picklist field is correctly mapped with DE attribute However update is not happening in Multiselect picklist field.

Answer (score 0):

The Right way to update multiselect picklist in Sales cloud from MC Journey is :- A; B; C
It works.